# SQL search using string variable

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm trying to create an sql search that will filter posts depending on the username stored in the string variable. I'm having issues with formatting it correctly and was wondering if anyone could help or tell me what i'm doing wrong.

```
foreach (var getrow in DB.Query("Select * from Posts where Username=" + username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
"Select * from Posts where Username='" + username + "'"
```

REFER TO SOLUTIONS BELOW. 
Note Ahmed's comment below ref SQL injection.

Comment: it will work fine as long as you don't have a single quote in the username.

Comment: *sarcasm* - nice solution. you are now prone to SQL injection attacks. let us know when your database gets dropped or tables being messed with.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way is...

```
var sql = "SELECT * From Posts WHERE username = @0"
```

...and then use `DB.Query(sql, username)`

This will help prevent [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You're more likely to be using Parameters in ASP.NET while trying to create a Connection to Database. It reduces the Risk of being attacked by an Hacker.

What you should try would be the following

```
foreach (var getrow in DB.Query(
"SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Username =@0", username);
```

Furthermore, go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection to learn more about SQL Injection and the ways you can use to prevent it.